# How do I make package files install to the correct location?

Tags: packaging

I have made a python application and managed to create a package. However, when I install the package, no files seem to be installed.

I have created an app.install file in the debian directory which contains:

```
bin/     /usr/bin
app.desktop     /usr/share/applications
```

The .py file is in debian/bin and the .desktop file is in debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be able to give you a more complete answer if I could see the package. From what you've provided, your `package.install` file should look like:

```
foo.py     usr/bin
debian/app.desktop     usr/share/applications
```

Also make sure that `package.install` (replace `package` with the actual name of your package) is in the `debian/` dir.

You should take a look at [the packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-install-file) and the man page for `dh_install`

Comment: I put it in debian/bin/ after reading a post on the Ubuntu forums. Where would you recommend I install a .py file?

Comment: In the root directory of the source package. Which after downloading your package, I see is what you have done.

Comment: Ok. Looking at the source package, I see the problem. First `package.install` needs to be in the `debian/`directory. Next, rename it to use your package's actual name, `bmi-calculator.install`. There's a few other minor issues in the package as well, but this will get the script and desktop file installed to the right location.

Comment: Thanks, it now installs correctly. When I said I had a .install file it was in the debian/directory, but it was actually called INSTALL which is why it didn't work.

Comment: I see a few lintian errors about the version and homepage, what other issues are there?

Comment: Like I said, minor stuff. Basically what lintian reports.