# Packing a .deb package correctly

Tags: packaging, deb

I'm trying to create a debian package of the [TIGCC](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/linux/), a C compiler for TI Calculators in correspondence with it's main developer, who is using Fedora and thus can only create and test RPMs.

I've got both the x86 binaries and the sources. However I'd prefer to build it from the sources. TIGCC consists of several small programs (C compiler, linker, assembly (a68k) compiler, ...) with their own makefiles.

I think the main problem I've got is: *How do I create a makefile calling the single one** (I guess `$(MAKE) -f ./rel/path/to/Makefile`) and *where do I have to place it?*

The second question is: How do I tell the builder *where the single parts are going to be installed* (compiled stuff to `/usr/tigcc/bin`, doc to `usr/share/doc/tigcc`, a.s.o.)?

I've already tried to create it from the binaries, but it crashed my testing system (saucy) and got some problem with it's dependencies (TIGCC depends on `libc6`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `debian/rules` file is what drives the building process. It is in fact a Makefile, but it also allows you to also take advantage of various packaging helpers. So your rules file might look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_build:
    $(MAKE) -f path/to/first/Makefile
    $(MAKE) -f path/to/second/Makefile
```

To install the files to the right place, use a `debian/install` file. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58743/570).

I suggest that you take a look at the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: You may also want to use pbuilder or sbuilder to test building your package in a virtual chroot.

Comment: It was because of the missing `debian/install`